# Continuity of $\nabla Z$ when the equation for $Z$ has a discontinuity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I am working in a problem of fluid dynamics (diffusion flames, exactly) and I am struggling to prove the continuity of a variable. The function $Z:R^n\to R$ is continuous, but not necessarily smooth. Being $H(Z-Z_0)$ the Heaviside function, the equation for $Z$ is
$$
H(Z-Z_0) \nabla \cdot (\mathbf{u} Z) = \nabla^2 Z,
$$
with $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u}=\sum_i \delta(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_i)$, it is, $\mathbf{u}$ is divergence-free almost everywhere, except for points inside the surface $Z=Z_0$ in which there are sources of $\mathbf{u}$.

> What can be said about the continuity of $\nabla Z$ across the surface defined by $Z=Z_0$?

(If it's relevant, the boundary condition to $Z$ is piecewise continuous).

That is my attempt, assuming that $H(Z-Z_0)\nabla Z = \nabla [H(Z-Z_0) Z]$: in that case, the equation can be written as
$$
\nabla \cdot (\mathbf{u} H(Z-Z_0) (Z-Z_1)) = \nabla^2 Z,
$$
in which $Z_1$ is an arbitrary constant and, supposedly, does not afect the differential operator. Integrating the equation in the volume enclosed by $Z=C$,
$$
\oint_{Z=C} H(Z-Z_0) (Z-Z_1) \mathbf{u}\cdot \mathbf{n} dS = \oint_{Z=C} \nabla Z \cdot \mathbf{n} dS.
$$
Using $C=Z_0\pm \epsilon$ and taking the limit $\epsilon \to 0$ leads to
$$
\oint_{Z=Z_0^+} (Z_0-Z_1) \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{n} dS = \oint_{Z=Z_0^+} \nabla Z \cdot \mathbf{n} dS,
$$
$$
0 = \oint_{Z=Z_0^-} \nabla Z \cdot \mathbf{n} dS.
$$
If $Z_1=Z_0$, $\nabla Z$ is continuous across the surface $Z=Z_0$; otherwise, it's discontinuous. However, if $Z_1$ could be chosen arbitrarily, it would make no difference to the behaviour of $\nabla Z$; if $Z_1=Z_0$ cannot be chosen, it's because $\nabla(Z-Z_0) \neq \nabla Z$ and $\nabla Z$ is not continuous at $Z=Z_0$.

Comment: I can't solve your original problem, but I can tell you that $ \int_{\partial \Omega} Z_1 u \cdot n dS = Z_1 \int_{\Omega} \nabla \cdot u = 0$ which recovers the independence in $Z_1$ (i.e. your proof doesn't work)

Comment: but maybe it can be rescued if you can prove that $\nabla Z\in C^0$ implies $F(c) = \int_{Z=c} \nabla Z \cdot n dS $ is continuous in $c$...?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @CalvinKhor. I think you are right with your first comment but actually $\nabla\cdot \mathbf{u} \neq 0$ in my particular problem, but $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{u} = \sum_i \delta (\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_i)$, since there are sources of $\mathbf{u}$ in the domain. Therefore, the net flow of $\mathbf{u}$ in a closed surface is not $0$.